# Extract id from inside class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am doing web scraping using beautiful. When I extracted class variable using find all I am getting array of data.

My query is how to extract id value from the extracted value. I tried the tag. but it did not help much.

I need following output

> measurement_a000_20c0_0002

## data[0]

```
<td class="measurement">
<div id="measurement_a000_20c0_0002">0.0</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Please share the array of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example just find the element and then use get id attribute. `element['id']`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<td class="measurement">
<div id="measurement_a000_20c0_0002">0.0</div>
</td>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
for item in soup.select(".measurement >div "):
    print(item['id'])
```

---

If you want to use find_all() try this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<td class="measurement">
<div id="measurement_a000_20c0_0002">0.0</div>
</td>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
for item in soup.find_all("td" , class_="measurement"):
    print(item.find_next('div')['id'])
```